# How to clear stale Server Name entries in the Sql Server Management Studio Connection Dialog?

Tags: sql-server-2008

All but one of the following entries are stale/don't exist and I just want them out. I've Ctrl-F'd the registry but to no avail. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This url provides a really handy utility that should probably have been built into SSMS to begin with:

 http://www.walkersretreat.co.nz/files/SSMSMRU.zip

Comment: the url has changed - see my answer for updated url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting this file `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell\mru.dat` or if you are on windows vista/Windows 7 look for a similar file in this folder (C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Shell)

Becareful as you will lose any customization that you have done.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059105/how-to-remove-server-name-items-from-history-of-sql-server-management-studio) and [this](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2006/10/25/SQL_Server_2005_Management_Studio__Clear_Recent_Servers_List.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Your first link was the answer for me on Win 7 / Sql Server 2008:SqlStudio.bin. Powershell use was necessary to avoid a total wipe of the user preferences.

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2012 Management Studio, this file has moved. It is now located at:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\
    SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\SqlStudio.bin
```

Comment: SSMS 2012 has the ability to remove servers built in without resorting to deleting this file. See my answer for link to blog post that explains how.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an open source UI to enable this (without losing other customisations) and posted it here: http://ssmsmru.codeplex.com/

Note that SSMS 2012 has the ability to delete servers build in. [See here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/managingsql/archive/2011/07/13/deleting-old-server-names-from-quot-connect-to-server-quot-dialog-in-ssms.aspx).

Over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059105/how-to-remove-server-name-items-from-history-of-sql-server-management-studio) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230159/how-to-delete-server-entries-in-sql-server-management-studios-connect-to-serve) are similar questions on SO. @arcticdev posted some code that I used in my UI